Using safe transaction builder in own app
Can I use transaction builder in my react app, using iframe in the way it looks in https://app.safe.global/apps/open?safe=sep:0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&appUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapps-portal.safe.global%2Ftx-builder
In my app iframe shows only a header, and looks like chains are not set up, so body returns , is there something I should sent to iframe so it would set up properly?
